# An inequality for the upper box dimension

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

***Exercise:*** Show that, for bounded sets $A$ and $B$, $$\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(A\cup B)=\max\{\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(A),\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(B)\},$$ where $\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(A)$ is the upper box dimension of the set $A$.

***So far:*** I have that $A\subset A\cup B$ and $B\subset A\cup B$, so clearly $\max\{\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(A),\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(B)\}\leqslant\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(A\cup B)$.

***For the other direction:*** I have that $N_{\delta}(A)+N_{\delta}(B)\leqslant2\max\{N_{\delta}(A),N_{\delta}(B)\}$ where $N_{\delta}(A)$ is the smallest number of closed balls which covers $A$. Clearly $\overline\dim_{\text{box}}(A\cup B)\leqslant N_{\delta}(A)+N_{\delta}(B)$, but I don't know where to go from there.

**Can someone tell me if what I have done is correct, whether or not there is an easier way, and how to finish it off please?**

Comment: you've almost done: you have $max\left \{ N_\delta (U), N_\delta (V) \right \}\leqslant N_\delta (U\cup V)\leqslant 2\cdot max\left \{ N_\delta (U), N_\delta (V) \right \}$. Any troubles with $2$ as a multiplier?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what your question means. Trouble with $2$?

Comment: @serg_1, is it anything to do with the fact that 'taking' the dimension of either side removes the $2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I think I have finally found the answer!**

Let $N_{\delta}(S)$ the smallest number of closed balls of radius $\delta$ which cover a set $S$. Clearly $E,F\subset E\cup F$, so $\max\{\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(E),\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(F)\}\leq\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(E\cup F)$.

Now, $N_{\delta}(E\cup F)\leq N_{\delta}(E)+N_{\delta}(F)\leq2\max\{N_{\delta}(E),N_{\delta}(F)\}$ and so $$\frac{\log(N_{\delta}(E\cup F))}{-\log(\delta)}\leq\max\left\{\frac{\log(N_{\delta}(E))}{-\log(\delta)},\frac{\log(N_{\delta}(F))}{-\log(\delta)}\right\}+\frac{\log(2)}{-\log(\delta)}.$$ Letting $\delta\to0$ gives that $\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(E\cup F)\leq\max\{\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(E),\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(F)\}$. Thus $\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(E\cup F)=\max\{\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(E),\overline{\text{dim}}_{box}(F)\}$.